# Remote terminal application

Tags: linux, terminal, console

Does anyone know if there exist an application which allows admin run other apps in kind of desktop environment.
What i mean is a kind of VNC application which only gives user the terminal console, but when user disconnects, the daemon will be still running, so for example:

- User connects to server and to the daemon.
- In this daemon console user runs **mc** starts copying a big file
- User disconects and connects again.
- The **mc** is still performing the copy of some big file etc.

I know that **nohup** allows to run app without in/out stream but one cannot "reconnect" to working process.

Comment: Perhaps `screen` or `tmux`...

Comment: When using `nohup`, the process keeps running in the background...  you can still query for it if you took note of the PID and then use `ps`.  Logging out and in again will not interrupt that process in any way.  For what you describe, then [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) could be the program you are looking for.

Comment: `screen` and `tmux` will do this for applications that run in a terminal window. I don't know if there's a VNC-like solution for a GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:
ssh to the remote server, then run screen or tmux (I prefer tmux). Exit by 'Ctrl-a d' or 'Ctrl-b d' respectively. When you ssh again there and run `tmux attach` or `screen -r` you will resume your session

Option 2:
To have graphical software resumed the same way, install xrdp on the remote server. This will start an X server on the remote host to which you can connect with e.g. an RDP client (rdesktop). The X session on the remote server will stay alive when you disconnect.